# PHP show data in checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox, foreach

How do I go about showing checkboxes that are in the jokecategory table as being selected, and those that arent to be shown but not checked. This is what I currently have:

```
<div class="control-group">
        <?php 
        $sql = 'SELECT jokecategory.joke_id, jokecategory.category_id, category.name 
        FROM jokecategory
        INNER JOIN category ON category.id = jokecategory.category_id
        WHERE joke_id= :joke_id';
        $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':joke_id', $id);
        $stmt->execute();

        ?>

        <fieldset>
        <legend class="control-label">Categories:</legend>
        <?php foreach ($stmt as $row) { ?>
            <div class="controls">
                <label for="category<?php echo($row['category_id']);?>">
                <input type="checkbox" id="category<?php echo $row['category_id']; ?>" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['category_id']; ?>" checked>
                <?php echo($row['name']); ?></label>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

with (data within the category table):

```
<?php $sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM category'; 
                    foreach ($dbConnection->query($sql) as $data) { ?>
                    <div class="controls">      
                        <label for="category<?php echo($data['id']);?>">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" id="category<?php echo($data['id']); ?>" value="<?php echo($data['id']); 



                        ?>">
                        <?php echo($data['name']); ?></label>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>

            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

Its in two segments at the moment as I was not sure on how to show the output the data into one merged group. so it goes like:

```
Joke id: xxxxx
joke_text: xxxxxx
author_name: xxxxx

categories 
1: [x]
2: [x]
3: [ ]
4: [ ]
```

Comment: Firstly, do you get data from the query? Have you tried to `print_r($data)` after fetching? Secondly, `$joke_id and other variables` will always have the last data of the query because those variables are not arrays. Third, your `foreach` calls `$data['category_id']`, is that correct?

Comment: I receive data to the all other fields. It is just the looping element that I was unsure of how to put together.

Comment: Having used 'print_r($data)' with 'joke.id = 28', it has 4x records under the jokecategory table. However, '$data['category_id'] shows only 1x data item from within the jokecategory table.

Comment: Could you share the `$data` array? ( print_r() )

Comment: $data output: Array ( [id] => 28 [joke_text] => jhohio [joke_date] => 2017-01-23 12:41:11 [name] => user [email] => user@email.com )
Array ( [joke_id] => 28 [category_id] => 4 [name] => Walk the bar )

Comment: $row output: Array ( [joke_id] => 28 [category_id] => 4 [name] => Walk the bar )

Comment: `$row['category_id']` holds the id `4` . So if you want to get the category id you can have access through that.

Comment: Ive managed to get the checkboxes in - see update. How do i show all checkboxes from the database and then just check just the ones within the jokecategory

Comment: So you want to show only `if $row['category_id'] == $joke_id` ?

Comment: not quite, see updated question

Comment: I can't really understand what do you want to do. Please ask a clear question..

Comment: look now, think that is more clear now.

Comment: the checkboxes values are ID's right?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile, that's correct. They are IDs.

Comment: ok, what u need to do is first query the iDs from the database then assign them to an array...  then on ur check boxes create them dynamically, use the in_array() function to check for the check boxes that are matches the array then have them checked

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yea that was it. sorted now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but - is $data["category_id"] really an array? If so, you could use the keypair in that array like this:

```
<?php foreach ($data['category_id'] as $id => $checkbox) { ?>
  <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="checkbox[]" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: how would I make $data["category_id"] into an array?

Answer (score 0):

probably it would be like below check your sql query and add category name to fetch and display eg. `category_name` used below
and make some changes as below

```
<fieldset>
        <legend class="control-label">Categories:</legend>
        <?php foreach ($data as $checkbox) { ?>
            <div class="controls">      
                <label for="category<?php echo($checkbox['category_id']); ?>">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" id="chk_category<?php echo($checkbox['category_id']); ?>" value="<?php echo($checkbox['category_id']); ?>">
                    <?php echo($checkbox['category_name']); ?></label>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I completely understand the question, but have you tried

`foreach ($data['category_id'] as $id => $checkbox)`